# Stop rh-python35 from replacing Python 2.7 in the `python` binary

Tags: python, rhel7

After I execute `scl enable rh-python35 bash`, my `python` becomes Python 3.5. Instead, I would like to have an environment in which Python 3.5 is only the `python3` and `python3.5` binaries, while `python` still points to Python 2.7. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I posted an answer, but I'm not sure this is all a good idea. It is generally accepted when working with virtualenvs for example, that `python` will refer to whatever the current env wants it to be. So don't rely on its value in a script. Python 2 is still available from `python2.7` or `python2` for interactive use.

Comment: Some distributions (Fedora, NixOS, ...) have `python` be Python 2.7, while Python 3.5 is made available as `python3`. I guess i am used to doing it this way and wanted to replicate it on rhel. I guess I don't really need it, it's just because of the familiarity. Archlinux (and rhel with rh-python35) have it this other way. I guess I'll just have to get used to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see by running `echo $PATH`, enabling `rh-python35` places its own bin directory at the beginning of the PATH so that any python found there is given precedent over the previous location:

```
$ type python
python is /opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/bin/python
```

where this location is itself is a symlink to python3:

```
$ ls -l /opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/bin/python
/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/bin/python -> python3
```

You can get your old Python back by running this:

```
mv /opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/bin/python{,.backup}
hash -r
```

Move the rh-python35's python to a backup location in the same folder and clear the hash.

Comment: Thanks, but you are probably right in your comment that doing this is probably not a good idea.